# call function from Controller in javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

using the d3.js graphs, I added the graph in the View cshtml page. now i want that the values in the graph will withdraw from my DB. 
so I wrote the following function in the Controller:

```
    protected int GetReadinessAvg()
    {
        var avgReadiness = 0;
        var countItems = 0;
        foreach (var item in db.Reviews)
        {
            avgReadiness = avgReadiness + item.LecturerReadine;
            countItems++;
        }
        avgReadiness = avgReadiness / countItems;

        return avgReadiness;
    }
```

This function works great and really return the relevant value.
Now, in the graph (the Js code), i want to use this value.
Here is what I trying to do..

```
 var freqData = [
                 { State: '2013', freq: { LecturerReadine: '<%=GetReadinessAvg()%>', LecturerTransferRate: 412, LecturerAttitude: 674, LecturerKnowledge: 2001 } }
                , { State: '2014', freq: { LecturerReadine: 932, LecturerTransferRate: 2149, LecturerAttitude: 418, LecturerKnowledge: 4726 } }
                , { State: '2015', freq: { LecturerReadine: 832, LecturerTransferRate: 1152, LecturerAttitude: 1862, LecturerKnowledge: 2135 } }
                ];
```

But call to the function: LecturerReadine: '<%=GetReadinessAvg()%>' isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As @Remy Grandin said, You can't directly call the controller method from JavaScript.
But you can call C# function in your .cshtml page. `Use @functions {..}`

```
@functions{

 protected int GetReadinessAvg()
    {
        var avgReadiness = 0;
        var countItems = 0;
        foreach (var item in db.Reviews)
        {
            avgReadiness = avgReadiness + item.LecturerReadine;
            countItems++;
        }
        avgReadiness = avgReadiness / countItems;

        return avgReadiness;
    }

}
```

then assign value.

```
var freqData = [
                 { State: '2013', freq: { LecturerReadine: '@GetReadinessAvg()', LecturerTransferRate: 412, LecturerAttitude: 674, LecturerKnowledge: 2001 } }
                , { State: '2014', freq: { LecturerReadine: 932, LecturerTransferRate: 2149, LecturerAttitude: 418, LecturerKnowledge: 4726 } }
                , { State: '2015', freq: { LecturerReadine: 832, LecturerTransferRate: 1152, LecturerAttitude: 1862, LecturerKnowledge: 2135 } }
                ];
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP MVC, you can't call a C# function directly. What you can do however is converting this function as an action and format a xml or json response with the controller `Content()` function.

With this xml or json available, you can make a simple js AJAX call and load the data into your graph.

Comment: ahh ok, i didn't knew it. maybe do you have a simple example of this?

Comment: An exemple : http://blog.kurtschindler.net/creating-an-actionresult-that-returns-xml-with-asp-net-mvc/ but they are many way to do it